# Cant add to (new) git-repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

Im new to git and just trying to follow instructions from bitbucket. Im trying to add files to a recently created git repo.

This is what Ive done:

```
cd myrepo
git init
git remote add origin https://pathfrombitbucket.org/myaccountname/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

**But nothing except the .gitignore-file has shown up in the web interface so far.** 
The gitignore-file has been used many times before and we have multiple existing repos.

How to a continue investigating from here?

**EDIT 1:**

@Lorenzo/Mateus/Andus... and all others :):

When I do push again, I get the error message

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://path-from_git/myrepo.git'
    hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
    hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
    hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
    hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**EDIT 2**
Trying to pull

```
>git pull  'https://path-from_git/myrepo.git'

 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

**EDIT 3**
Didnt understand the last message(from EDIT 2) so I removed the repo and started over.

Comment: push after the commit

Comment: As the hint states, do a `git pull` beforehand. That should fetch and merge the most current code changes from the remote repository to your local repository. If no merge conflicts occure (which I assume from your description) you have to `git commit` first and than `git push` again

Answer (score 0):

Use `git push` like you did before adding the files. `Git add` just stashes the files and with commit you commit them to the local HEAD. In order to see them in the repo you have to push your local HEAD to the remote repo with `git push`.

Here the cycle (from [rogerdudler's great tutorial](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html)):

[image: git trees]

As you see, at the point of commiting your files they are still in your local computer and not on the remote repo.

**In response to your edit:**

If you use an IDE like IntelliJ or VS Code (or similar) you can just pull the changes from the remote origin and merge them with your local files. You cannot push until you resolved all conflicts between your local HEAD and the remote HEAD. [Rogerdudler's tutorial](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html) shows, how you can do it with the git shell (under update & merge) but I think it's to cumbersome.

Since you just created the repo you can just `git clone` it and you are already up to date and don't have to merge all your changes.

Answer (score 0):

After I got the error messages AnDus advices me to do another pull, thanks!

I did this but got another error message "refusing to merge unrelated histories". I have no idea what this means, nor why its nearly impossible to add files to a brand new repository. But I found the flag

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

This made the pull-request to go through and I could do the second push.

Although, git seems to ignore my .gitignore-file :/

Answer (score -1):

You should do the `git push` again after your commit.
Then the code changes should show up in the remote repository.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply! See edit in question (I put it there because of formatting)